# How to get the value of style attribute of an element using selenium webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I want to get the style value from an element and assign it to a string var.
I tried using the below code but it returns a value of 'rgb(173, 255, 47)' when I'm trying to return the value 'background:#ADFF2F"':

```
IWebElement highlightedText = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("firstHeading")).FindElement(By.CssSelector("th-highlight-span"));
actualHighlightColour = highlightedText.GetAttribute("style");
```

This is the src code from the web page I want to get the value of style from:

```
<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" lang="en">
 ::before
 <th-highlight-span style="background:#ADFF2F" data- 
 rwstate="ss">California Proposition 218 (1996)</th-highlight-span>
```

The code I tried to use returns 'rgb(173, 255, 47)' which can be found here but I want to return background: #ADFF2F:

```
element.style {
background: #ADFF2F;
background-image: initial;
background-position-x: initial;
background-position-y: initial;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: initial;
background-repeat-y: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: rgb(173, 255, 47);
```

Comment: So, do you have any error messages?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov no I don't get any error messages, I get rgb(173, 255, 47) returned and assigned to actualHighlightColour var but I want to return background:#ADFF2F ;

Comment: Try `highlightedText.GetCssValue("background");`

Comment: @AmanB when I use that it returns the following "rgb(173, 255, 47) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box"

Answer (score 1):

Convert RGB to hex format

```
 String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
```

This will return the hex in small alphabet and if want this in caps then simply replace `x` with `X`

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to retrieve the **style** attribute i.e. the text **background:#ADFF2F** you can use the following solution :

```
actualHighlightColour = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("h1.firstHeading#firstHeading>th-highlight-span")).GetAttribute("style");
```

### Update

As the above expression still returns `background: rgb(173, 255, 47);`, get the output as **rgb(173, 255, 47)** you can use the [`GetCssValue()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetCssValue.htm) method and you can use the following solution:

```
actualHighlightColour = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("h1.firstHeading#firstHeading>th-highlight-span")).GetCssValue("background");
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to convert #ffffff to #fff or #fff to #ffffff while asserting the background color rgb(255,255,255) returned by Selenium getCssValue(“background”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767206/how-to-convert-ffffff-to-fff-or-fff-to-ffffff-while-asserting-the-background)

Comment: I tried this but it returns "background: rgb(173, 255, 47);" and not background:#ADFF2F

Comment: @Tester_Giant1 Can you try the updated answer and let me know the status please?